# Using ArcMap I want to add new Fields into a gdb using Python

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool

I'm new learning as I go, I have read some of the Answers posted, and I've gotten this far, I was able to add a new field to a GBD, I wanted to have the Length be 50, but it created a field with 255, so I didn't get something quite right  the code I used  below  the feature class is wax_ru the Field name is HN_AW  Text is the Type of Field, and 50 is the Default Value I wanted, but as I stated it created the field with 255

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:\Users\angelaw\OneDrive - TomTom\Resources\Australia\PSMA_MAY_2018\PSMA_Deltas_test\PSMA_MAY_deltas.gdb"

arcpy.AddField_management ("wax_ru", "HN_AW","TEXT",50)
```

Comment: See `arcpy.AddField_management` parameters here: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-field.htm

Answer (score 3):

You should specify parameter names, the code will be easier to understand and you dont have to keep track of parameter position. [Also use `r` in front of path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19034822/unknown-python-expression-filename-r-path-to-file):

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\angelaw\OneDrive - TomTom\Resources\Australia\PSMA_MAY_2018\PSMA_Deltas_test\PSMA_MAY_deltas.gdb"

arcpy.AddField_management(in_table="wax_ru", field_name="HN_AW", field_type="TEXT", 
                         field_length=50)
```

You are providing 50 as the fourth parameter which is field_precision. You can also add empty strings to line up 50 with the right parameter:

```
arcpy.AddField_management("wax_ru","HN_AW","TEXT","","",50)
```

Comment: What does the r do?

Comment: @AngelaS: Without it some of the \-signs in combination with certain letters can be interpreted as for example a new line = path will not work

Comment: @AngelaS About the "r" before the string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals